# Function of “was” in Phrases

Tags: standard-german

What is the function of “was” in the phrase “in etwas das, was”? Are there other phrases where it functions similarly? More generally, how do you use “was” outside of questions?

[Context: “Ich bin zweisprachig aufgewachsen und auch wieder nicht. Meine Eltern haben beide Plattdeutsch gesprochen, konnten aber auch ziemlich akzentfreies Hochdeutsch – in etwa das, was Philip Newton in seiner Antwort als ‘norddeutsches Hochdeutsch’ beschrieben hat.”]

Answer (score 1):

> in etwa<s>***s***</s> das, was

Did you note that the word here is "*etwa*" and not "*etwas*"?

("*in etwa*" = "nearly", "*etwas*" = "something")

> What is the function of “was” in the phrase ... ?

**Background**

The substantive of a sub-ordinate clause can be "*that*" or "*which/who*" in English. In German it can be "*der/die/das*" or "*welcher/welche/welches*". (While I did not find any example where you cannot freely chose between "*der/...*" and "*welcher/...*")

I sometimes heared that "*was*" is used instead of "*das*" or "*welches*" (in the case of words with a neuter gender):

> My brother sits in the car **which** just drives by.
>   Mein Bruder sitzt im Auto, **was** gerade vorbei fährt.
>   *(Instead of:)* Mein Bruder sitzt im Auto, **das** gerade vorbei fährt.

So the word "*was*" is the subject of the sub-ordinate clause here.

However it can also be the accusative object of the sub-ordinate clause:

> There is the car **which** I own.
>   Dort steht das Auto, **was** ich besitze.
>   *(Instead of:)* Dort steht das Auto, **das** ich besitze.

I'm not absolutely sure, but as far as I know using "*was*" instead of "*das*/*welches*" is not allowed in Hochdeutsch but only in some dialects.

**In Hochdeutsch ...**

... the word "*was*" is used as subject or accusative object of the sub-ordinate clause in one situation: When some subject, nominative object or accusative object is completely described by a sub-ordinate clause.

In English you would use the word "*what*" in this case:

> I buy **what** makes me happy.
>   Ich kaufe, **was** mich glücklich macht. (1)
>   Ich kaufe **das, was** mich glücklich macht. (2)

Because I'm not 100% sure I don't like to describe the difference between the two German sentences here.

However in some cases you only use a sub-ordinate clause beginning with "*was*" (1) while in other cases you use the word "*das*" before the sub-ordinate clause (2).

The word "*was*" is also used when a sub-ordinate clause is used with "*alles*" and some similar words (I don't have a complete list):

> I like **everything that** is red.
>   Ich mag **alles, was** rot ist.

Comment: @PiedPiper: Nein, das Fragezeichen gehört nicht zum Zitat. Die Darstellung ist da nicht ganz glücklich - erst im Beispiel darunter erschließt sich, was das was bedeuten  soll.

Answer (score 1):

It's one word that you can use to introduce a relative clause. And it's the same as in English!

You can translate "That's what I like." by "Das ist das, was ich mag."

Comment: Ich würde noch vermuten, dass es vor allem benutzt wird, um ein doppeltes "das" zu vermeiden, obwohl auch "... in etwa das, das Phil Newton beschrieben hat" ginge.